# User access in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database that uses User Code so not everyone can update all screens. I am trying to add this code to access 2010 database but keep getting an error when I try to run Show Users modules. It keeps stopping at Dim cn AS New ADODB.Connection- I do not know what this is or where to look. Can you help?

Comment: Perhaps the new db does not have a reference set for ADO.  Check by opening the VB Editor environment.  Then choose Tools->References from it's main menu.  Do you have any version of *Microsoft ActiveX Data Object Library* checked?

Comment: no I do not have any checked?

Comment: Check one and tell us what happens.

Comment: when I try to select Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library(same one from old database) I get the following error: Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library

Comment: No, that is DAO not ADO.  Scroll further down the list of choices until you get to those whose names start with *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects*

Comment: I selected on and it is working on

Comment: I don't understand working on.  Does that mean problem solved?